# Finding the actual point of error in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a question similar to the question posted [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/108dedff-a110-4d05-b7ff-274dab0f12e3/vs-c-compiler-errors-in-internal-header-files?forum=vcgeneral).

I'm working on a complex C++ project with thousands of files and I have several changes done. Now when I build the project, it throws errors in some standard library header files like xutility etc in the 'Error List' window.

But then it is not showing me which part of my code lead to such errors deep within the standard library header files. How do I get that info? The answers in the above link are not satisfactory.

Comment: Btw I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: *Btw I'm using Visual Studio 2010* -- If your changes involved introducing anything C++11 or beyond, you are risking things using such an out-of-date compiler.  It has minimal support for C++ 11, and is even broken (at runtime) for C++ 11 features that are not fully supported.

Comment: Sorry, but you'll have to tackle this one alone. I can't help you since I don't have a crystal ball. Some thoughts on possible culprits: precompiled headers, intellisense doing it's own thing (both could be resolved by force recompiling the whole project), forgot to include a header, forgot to declare a symbol, an extra symbol (like a comma) at the end of a header or near an `#include`, or using newer features in this old compiler (like c++11 and beyond). Whatever it may be you won't find the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when this happens to me I go to the Output tab and ctrl-F `error`. This usually finds a number of `error`s tracing back to the source file and line.

If anyone has a better way of doing this, I'd love to know about it too.

Comment: That's a great place to start looking because the output tab often holds much more information that the Error List. Excellent advice. Unfortunately it's more comment than answer.